# Testing AngularJS resource with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, angular-ui-router, angular-resource

I would like to test my resource with following URL:

```
    $resource(API_URL+'items/:id', {});
```

Where API_URL equals /app/api/

```
describe('item',function(){
    it('should return same item id',function(){ 
        $httpBackend.expectGET(API_URL+'items/1').respond({id:1});
        var result = ItemService.item.get({id:1});
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(result.id).toEqual(1);
    });
});
```

But the problem is that this test fails for some strange reason:

```
    Error: Unexpected request: GET modules/home/partials/home.html
    No more request expected
        at $httpBackend
```

And when I add slash to $httpBackend URL like this:

```
    $httpBackend.expectGET(API_URL+'/items/1').respond({id:1});
```

It throws following expection:

```
    Error: Unexpected request: GET /app/api/items/1
    Expected GET /app/api//items/1
        at $httpBackend
```

Note double slash in expected GET.

How to fix it?

Update:
Code from ItemService:

```
    var itemService = angular.module("ItemServiceModule", []);
    itemService.factory("ItemService", [ "$resource", "API_URL", function($resource,API_URL) {
        var itemService = {
            item: $resource(API_URL+'items/:id', {})
        };
        return itemService;
    }]);
```

Update2:
If I change httpBackend url like this (just add localhost and not adding slash before items):

```
      $httpBackend.expectGET('http://localhost:8080'+API_URL+'items/1').respond({id:1});
```

Then the error is:

```
    Error: Unexpected request: GET /app/api/items/1
    Expected GET http://localhost:8080/app/api/items/1
        at $httpBackend
```

Update3:
If I for example hard code that API_URL like this:

```
 var url = 'app/api/items/1';
        $httpBackend.expectGET(url).respond({id:1});
```

The error is:

```
 Error: Unexpected request: GET /app/api/items/1
    Expected GET app/api/items/1
        at $httpBackend
```

But when I add slash at the begining of url, then it requests home partial modules/home/partials/home.html as with API_URL.

```
    Error: Unexpected request: GET modules/home/partials/home.html
    No more request expected
        at $httpBackend
```

Comment: Show your code for `ItemService`

Comment: How is the variable `API_URL` passed

Comment: I am pretty sure that API_URL is not the reason for this problem. Service itself works in the app and properly injected into the test (I tested with console.log). Otherwise I wouldn't get any of these urls in the exception message.

Comment: Ok, the first error maybe due to some other test. Is this the only test running?

Comment: Other test are running but they all pass without this test. I updated question once again, maybe it will help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was with ui-router. Namely, the following configuration:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
```

I just needed to eliminate this configuration in the tests:

```
beforeEach(module(function ($urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function(){return false;});
}));
```

Found this solution on https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/212